# Suspicous windows-like notifications from brave web browser (allegedly)

Tags: security, notification, browser, malware

I almost always never allow websites to send me notifications, however recently I've been getting a lot of notifications from this specific website which is why i became a little bit suspicious, not only because i do not remember allowing notifications from this website. But also because the notification bar looks like an old and poorly designed windows notification. Here's the image attachment. [image]

As you can see, this doesn't look like a system notification, so my question is; do you think this is a part of some malicious program? And if so is there anyway specific of telling?

Comment: Most likely those are crypto ads from brave browser itself. In my opinion, Firefox is a better alternative.

Comment: Ok thank you, but brave has a very powerful ads-blocker which is why I use it.

Comment: If it's just matter of ad-blocking, I would highly recommend, Firefox with extension, uBlock Origin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/ ; and you can use powerful blocklist like: https://oisd.nl/downloads with uBlock Origin. Thanks.

Comment: @razi-falah Did the answer resolve your issue? If yes, please accept the answer; it would help others too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely those are crypto ads from Brave browser itself. As per Brave forums and other sites, you can disable these ads.

**Disable Brave private ads**:

Open Brave browser and go to: `brave://settings/rewards`

and turn off the toggle for Brave private ads.

As per MakeUseOf: If you want to take this a step further:

Turn off the toggle next to **Auto-Contribute** and disable any toggle below **Tip** buttons.

[image: Disable Brave private ads]

**Disable crypto ads from the new tab page**:

There’s one more place Brave will show you crypto ads. On the new tab page.

To remove these ads, open a new tab and click Customize. Then, disable Show Sponsored Images.

[image: Disable crypto ads from the new tab page]

**Disable the Brave rewards button**:

Go to brave://settings/appearance

Find the hide Brave rewards button and turn on the toggle next to it.

[image: Disable the Brave rewards button]

**Additional note**: In the comment, you mentioned the primary reason to use Brave is ad-blocking.

In that case, I would recommend to use Firefox with extension, [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) alongwith powerful blocklist like: [oisd blocklist](https://oisd.nl/downloads). Also note that oisd is one of many blocklists out there to use with uBlock Origin.

This is how you can add oisd blocklist: uBlock Origin settings > Filter lists > My filters > paste: `https://big.oisd.nl/` > Click: `Import`.

Reference links:

https://www.makeuseof.com/brave-disable-crypto-features/

https://community.brave.com/t/crypto-notifications/379238

https://community.brave.com/t/brave-crypto-notifications/257295